# css path errors on spring boot

Tags: css, spring, thymeleaf

When i use the url to list the product that i have and click edit to update my product the page is not rendred with css which is definded  in the path of LINK tag , otherwise this path work great in other forms...
Folders that contains the file into the project:

-> Static 
 ---> css 
 -----> bootstrap.min.css:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}"
        />

    <title>Nouveau Produits</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        .........
   </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: did you try `./css/boostrap.min.css` ?

Comment: @ochi i'm workin with thymeleaf !! did this work ?

Comment: I am asking you if you tried it yet

Comment: @ochi yes, but still not working

Comment: we need more information... can you check if you get any console errors? (i.e. 404) Or server errors? (i.e. exceptions)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()    bootstrap.min.css

Comment: What's the full URL for the resource?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161559/discussion-between-khadhri-hamza-and-ochi).

Comment: @ochi i  edited my post with picture!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Make sure case matches if capital.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your folder name Static to static. and add this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/boostrap.min.css">
```

Comment: the same thing... but i'm working with 
 thymeleaf : th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}"